# babel-loader@7.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none was installed

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

When doing

```
npm install babel-loader
```

I get

```
├── babel-loader@7.1.1 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2 || 3

npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none was installed
```

How can I address this warning or what will it mean if I don't / can't ?

Versions:

```
$ webpack -v
3.3.0
$ node -v
v6.11.1

react@15.6.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this:

```
npm install webpack@3
```

Then when I do `npm install babel-loader` I get other optional dependency warnings, so not sure if that is ok.
Most about `fsevents` which seems to be something about my Ubuntu OS

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0  
(node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2:
wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: It's an optional dependency that depends on macOS, which you're not running, so it's okay.

Comment: That's OK. If `babel-loader` didn't complain about webpack, you are good to go